# For loop in Django template causing error when I use the add filter

Tags: python, django, for-loop

I am trying to add two variables together in my template that will combine two scores together and print the value. The problem is when the loop gets to a game that hasn't happened yet it kicks out an error because the variable doesn't exist yet.

What am I supposed to add to skip games in the loop that have no score?

```py
    {% for game in games %}
        <p class="light-blue text-center">
            Total: {{ game.scoreboard.score.home|add:game.scoreboard.score.away }}
        </p>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is typically something that does *not* belong in the template, but in the model.

Comment: The data is coming from an API

Comment: then you pre-process it in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice to implement this in the model, not in the template.

So if you have a model for `Score` for example, you can implement this as:

```
class Score(models.Model):
    home = models.IntegerField()
    away = models.IntegerField()
    
    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.home + self.away
```

and then render this as:

```
{% for game in games %}
    <p class="light-blue text-center">
        Total: {{ game.scoreboard.score.total }}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

If the data is is a structure of dictionaries. You can preprocess this in the view with:

```
def my_view(request):
    # … some data …
    for game in data['games']:
        score = game['scoreboard']['score']
        score['total'] = score['home'] + score['away']
    # …
```

if not all games have a scoreboard, you can first check if that is an element of the dictionary:

```
def my_view(request):
    # … some data …
    for game in data['games']:
        if 'scoreboard' in game and 'score' in game['scoreboard']:
            score = game['scoreboard']['score']
            score['total'] = score['home'] + score['away']
    # …
```

Comment: I get the same error because as soon as there is no 'scoreboard' the loop stops.

Comment: @RyanThomas: but based on your template the `game` should have a `scoreboard. if that is not the case than something is wrong with the structure of the data, and it will not work in the template, and you thus should inspect and correct the view according to the data.

Comment: It is a dictionary with information on all the games of the day. When a game is completed there is scoreboard attached to that game. So now because it is the middle of the day, half the games have a scoreboard and half don't yet. So I need some sort of if statement or something saying only if the value is there.

Comment: @RyanTHomas: then you can first check if that is a member of the dictionary. See edit

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!